# Problema al asignar valores a una struct de datos

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, struct

Mi problema es que al intentar darle valores a una struct.

La struct esta definida asi:

```
typedef struct VarEntera {
    int valor;
    char *nombre;
} VarEntera;
```

y la asignación esta escrita asi:

```
VarEntera *VarInt = NULL;
    VarInt->valor = 21;
    strcpy(VarInt->nombre ,&linea[4] );
```

La cosa es que compila bien y al ejecutar el programa se pega en la parte de VarInt->valor = 21 y despues se cierra. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Esta linea: `VarEntera *VarInt = NULL;` estas usando un puntero que no has inicializado. Los punteros pueden apuntar a NULL (como estás haciendo tú) o a un objecto válido que este en la memoria.
En tu caso estás invocando UB (comportamiento indefinido) ya que estas desrreferenciando un puntero nulo, además tienes otro problema, tu estructura tiene otro puntero dentro de ella que tampoco has inicializado reservando memoria o apuntando a un objecto válido.

Tienes dos opciones: la primera es reservar memoria dinámica llamando a malloc definida en stdlib.h, lo cuál quedaría así: `VarEntera *VarInt = malloc(sizeof(VarEntera));` y luego ya podrías usar ese puntero como tienes publicado `VarInt->valor = 21;` si también quieres usar el puntero nombre como tienes en tu código tienes que reservar memoria:

```
const char *p = "Juan";
VarInt->nombre = malloc(strlen(p)+1); // reservamos memoria para Juan, +1 porque las cadenas en c acaban con \0
strcpy(VarInt->nombre,p); // copiamos Juan a VarInt->nombre
```

Recuerda liberar la memoria cuando ya no la uses usando la función free.

```
free(VarInt->nombre); // orden inverso al reservado
free(VarInt);
```

La segunda es creando el objecto por ti mismo y apuntado con el puntero a ese objecto para modificarlo:

```
VarEntera VarNuevo;
VarEntera *VarInt = &VarNuevo;
VarInt->valor = 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

El puntero "VarInt" apunta a NULL y luego usas el puntero para mandar un valor a una dirección de memoria que desconocemos pero que el programa no tiene acceso y por lo tanto abortará. 
La primera solución, es darle la dirección base de la estructura "VarEntera" al puntero "VarInt".
Ejemplo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   VarEntera var = {5, "David"};
   VarEntera *VarInt = &var;
   VarInt->valor = 21;
   return 0;
}
```

Otra solución es reservando memoria dinámicamente:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    VarEntera* VarInt = malloc(sizeof(VarEntera));
    VarInt->valor = 21;
    free(VarInt);
    return 0;
}
```

De ese modo evitas la violación de segmento (intentar sobreescribir el contenido de una dirección cuando el programa no tiene acceso a ello).